# NoReverseMatch at /polls/1/ in Django 4.0

Tags: html, django

I am learning Django from the official documentation, and getting this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /polls/1/
Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/\\Z']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/
Django Version: 4.0
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/\\Z']
```

These are my urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='polls'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/result/', views.result, name='result'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

View.py File:

```
def index(request):
    latest_questions = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', {'latest_questions': latest_questions})


def detail(request, question_id):
    detail = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'detail': detail})


def result(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("This is the result for question no. %s" % question_id)


def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You are voting for question %s" % question_id)
```

And this is where the problem lies on detail.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'vote' question.id %}" method="post">
```

Comment: There is no question in the template, it should be `{% url 'vote' detail.id %}`...

Comment: Thanks! It did help, but can you explain a bit.